# Trying to retrieve the index number of the lowest number in an array of doubles in java

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to loop through an array of objects (students) and find the index of the student (stored in temp) who has the lowest score for a given test (which). There may be any number of tests here. I have no idea where I went wrong here and have been trying for hours.

```
   public int findLowestExam(int which) {
       int returnVal = 0; // index of student whose score is lowest
           
       if ( which > 0 && which <= students[0].getExams().length ){ // if exam no is in range (number of exams)
           which = which - 1; // for array index, 1 = 0 etc
           double temp[] = new double[students[0].getExams().length]; // temp is array that stores exam scores
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // iterate through number of students
               double temp2[] = students[i].getExams(); // temp2 stores exam scores of student number i temporarily in array of doubles
               temp[i] = temp2[which]; // temp2[which] will get whichever temporary exam score you specify, store it in array temp. 
               // find lowest score 
               double min = temp[0]; 
               for ( int j = 1; j < temp.length; j++ ) { //iterates through however many tests there are 
                   
                   if ( min < temp[j] ) {
                       min = temp[j];
                   }
                   returnVal = j;
           }
               }
       } else {
             return -1;
        }
       return returnVal;
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. You say that temp contains the value you're looking for, but you create it yourself. If expect the test scores to be passed into the function. The `which ` parameter also makes no sense because it refers to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `index` of the lowest scored student from an `array`, you can achieve that by the following algorithm:

1. Loop through the array and marked the lowest index up to that index.

For example - let's you have an array of 3 students who scored like following:

```
Student1 - 30
Student2 - 22
Student3 - 35
```

You can traverse the array once, and mark the lowest scored student

```
minMarks = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
lowestIndex = -1;
index = 0; 
for(Student stud : array){
  if( stud.getMarks() < minMarks){
      minMarks = stud.getMarks();
      lowestIndex = index;
  }
  // increment index
  index += 1;
}
```

At the end of the loop, you will have the index `lowestIndex` of the lowest scored student.